# How to create a gradient background on infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to create an infinite scrolling page where the background is a gradient that changes according to the scroll position.

I found this infinite scroll code that works with the time and date. I would like to replace it with the gradient task.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Scroll me</h1>

<script>
  function populate() {
    while(true) {
      let windowRelativeBottom = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      if (windowRelativeBottom > document.documentElement.clientHeight + 100) break;
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p>Date: ${new Date()}</p>`);
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', populate);

  populate(); // init document
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Any code?

Comment: Please supply your infinite scroll code

Comment: if it is infinite how do you know what the gradient should be based off of?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302983/infinitely-sliding-css3-gradient

Comment: just added the code. i think the gradient could be just a looped block of color throughout the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple really, no need to complicate this. Given a gradient is treated like a background image, you can repeat it as such. Backgrounds can repeat "infinitely" so, we can just set the vertical height of our background to be something we know will repeat. i.e. with your gradient defined, use `background-size`:

```
background-size: 100% 400vh;
background-repeat: repeat-y; /* this is set to repeat by default, but putting this in helps drive the point home */
```

Our gradient will repeat every 4 viewport heights and the document is constantly increasing with height due to your JS so we see it repeat infinitely. Just ensure the gradient ends with the same colour it starts with or you'll see a cut.

Don't open this codepen if you don't want to look at some flashing colours: https://codepen.io/joshdavenport/pen/rNNOJWM